# sidebar does not scroll to the bottom when unfolding menu items

Tags: css, menu

I'm using a layout for a web app where I have a sidebar menu on the left. The menu is made of several items which can unfold to show the menu sub items. My problem is : when several items are unfolded, the height of the menu side bar exceeds the height of the screen. Moreover,  the sidebar does allow ot scroll to see the last menu items in the list.

Here is the css part for my sidebar :

```
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 260px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 260px;
  height: calc(100vh - 64px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

As you will understand, I would like the sidebar to scroll, but I can't get it to work.

Any idea about how to achieve that ?

thanks a lot.

Adam

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you achieve that

```
<style>
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 260px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.sidebar-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 260px;
  height: calc(100vh - 64px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
</style>

<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That did not make any change.